# cron job setup using rpm is not working

Tags: centos, cron, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I've below cron file

```
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin

    LOG_DIR=/var/log/myapp-services-cron
    MYAPP_SERVICES_DIR=/opt/myorg/apps/myapp-services

    * * * * * myappcron node $MYAPP_SERVICES_DIR/scripts/processor.js &>> $LOG_DIR/processor.log 2>&1
```

This is created by below [rpm.spec](https://github.com/rajcspsg/cron-demo/blob/master/utils.spec) file

```
    Summary: Utility for testing RPM creation
    Name: utils
    Version: 1.0.0
    Release: 1
    License: GPL
    URL: http://www.both.org
    Group: System
    Packager: Rajkumar Natarajan
    Requires: bash
    Requires: nodejs >= 8.1.2
    BuildRoot: ~/rpmbuild/

    %description
    A collection of utility scripts for testing RPM creation.


    %prep
    ################################################################################
    # Create the build tree and copy the files from the development directories    #
    # into the build tree.                                                         #
    ################################################################################
    echo "BUILDROOT = $RPM_BUILD_ROOT"


    %pre

    %build

    %install
    sudo mkdir -p /etc/cron.d
    sudo mkdir -p /var/log/myapp-services-cron
    sudo mkdir -p /var/lock/myapp-services-cron
    sudo mkdir -p /opt/myorg/apps/myapp-services
    sudo cp -r /home/vagrant/cron-demo %{buildroot}/
    sudo cp -r  %{buildroot}/cron-demo/crontab /etc/cron.d/myapp-services-cron-scripts
    sudo cp -r %{buildroot}/cron-demo/scripts /opt/myorg/apps/myapp-services/


    %post

    %files
    /cron-demo/

    %postun

    %clean
    sudo rm -rf %{buildroot}/

    %changelog
```

The cron file is invoking a nodejs script every single minute. But somehow the cron is not trigged.

OS details are -

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
Release:    7.5.1804
Codename:   Core
```

I've user myappcron created. Nodejs and scripts/processor are also in correct location.

Any idea why the cron is not trigged?

Answer (score 3):

You are confused about the meaning of the `%install` section.

The sections

- %prep
- %build
- %install
- %check

run on the machine where you **build** the `rpm` package, not on the machine where the rpm is installed. You should **never use sudo** inside your spec file. Probably you want something like this (I have  only written the part concerning your cron.d file, you can extrapolate for the other files you need):

```
%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/etc/cron.d
cp -r /cron-demo/crontab %{buildroot}/etc/cron.d/myapp-services-cron-scripts

%files
/etc/cron.d/myapp-services-cron-scripts
```